# Smooth Music Transitions in the BGE?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks, properties, audio

I have several pieces of music in my game's scene I want to play based on an assigned number in a game property.  However I don't want the transitions to be abrupt, but rather smooth (as in when the property controlling which song is to be played changes, the already-playing song fades out while the new song fades in simultaneously.)  Is there a way to do this in the BGE?